# How to run multiple INSERT queries in a transaction and use insert id?

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql-insert-id

I need to insert data into 3 tables and need to get the id of last inserted query into `shopper` table. I know this is doable by running

```
$conn -> insert_id;
```

in a single query but in my case I need to create a transaction with rollback in case of any failure. something like

```
$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);

$stmt1 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shopper (usersID, parentJob, phoneNumber,address) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt1->bind_param("ssss", $userId, $parentJob, $phoneB, $addressB);

$stmt2 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shipment (shipmentID, usersID,..) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt2->bind_param("ssss", $userId, ...);

$stmt3 = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO address (addressID, usersID, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt3->bind_param("ss", $userId, ...);

$conn->begin_transaction();
if ($stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute()) {
    $conn->commit();
} else {
    $conn->rollback();
}

$conn->close();
```

As you can see I am trying to pass last inserted `usersID` as Foreign Key into `shipment`  and `address` tables. so how can I do this when committing all of them together like

```
if ($stmt1->execute() && $stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute()) {
    $conn->commit();
} else {
    $conn->rollback();
}
```

Comment: Just get and pass. It has nothing to do with transactions

Comment: I see. Well you can make it `if ($stmt1->execute() && $userId = $conn->insert_id && $stmt2->execute() && $stmt3->execute()) {` but better configure mysqli to throw exceptions and get rid of this if condition at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Exceptions offer enormous help with transactions. Hence [configure mysqli to throw exceptions](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting). Not only for transactions but because it's the only proper way to report errors in general.

With exceptions your code will be plain and simple

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$conn = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS, DBNAME);
$conn->set_charset('utf8mb4');

$conn->begin_transaction();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shopper (usersID, parentJob, phoneNumber,address) VALUES (null, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sss", $parentJob, $phoneB, $addressB);
$stmt->execute();
$userId = $conn->insert_id;

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO shipment (shipmentID, usersID,..) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $userId, ...);
$stmt->execute();

$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO address (addressID, usersID, ...) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("ss", $userId, ...);
$stmt->execute();

$conn->commit();
```

in case of error an exception will be thrown and a transaction will be rolled back automatically.

Comment: Thanks for reply but is it Ok to have only one stmt here?

Comment: Yes of course. It's just a disposable variable, you are using it for one query and then reusing for another